# Bash split file into streams by pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'd like to split a file such as:

```
#define MACRO "exists"

code *code(code code, code code_code) {
  code more_code;
  return more_code;
}

#define THING

// etc
```

into two streams that I can manipulate with other utilities before recombining - that is, modify some lines based on a pattern with specific commands, and the lines that don't match the pattern with different commands.

I imagine this would require the use of named pipes.

My current approach reads the file twice, and uses grep to filter the lines:

```
FILE="example.txt"
grep '^#' < "$FILE" | cpp -P > combined.txt
grep -v '^#' < "$FILE" | awk '{ print $4 }' >> combined.txt
```

Is there any way to use `sed` or another utility to split a file up by a pattern?

Comment: Doesn't need to be named pipes.  Could be solved with a number of named files.

Comment: Yeah but then you'd have to go through the filesystem. Less optimal for larger files.

Comment: Pipes are handled pretty much the same way.  Anyway, a modern implementation is unlikely to write much of the data to disk–it would be mostly in cache–unless the files are huge (>2G).

Comment: You can use bash to loop over each line in the file `for a in $(< file.txt); do`, then process the grep's simply on the lines themselves quickly.

Comment: Along with the idea from @A.Danischewski, this may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process

Comment: @A.Danischewski That doesn't loop over lines; it loops over space-delimited words in the file.

Comment: @skeggse your approach is probably the most reasonable one. It's  possible to use two named pipes in combination with sed's [w  command](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-how-to-write-to-a-file-using-sed/), `cat`ing them in the end, but the whole setup is pretty awkward.

Comment: @liborm sure it'd be awkward, but wouldn't it work?

Comment: @A.Danischewski I'm well aware of what `$(< ...)` is. However, `IFS` is *not* normally a newline; it's default value is a space, a tab, and a newline. Please read [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @A.Danischewski "the IFS is normally approximately a newline". That "approximately" makes a huge difference in how your suggested for loop will work.

Comment: @chepner first it's a comment not a complete answer, but to be clear if your text has spaces you can process it as follows: `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(< file.txt); do`.

Comment: That may not work either; the command substitution is subject to pathname expansion which may alter the contents as assigned to the loop variable.

Comment: Suppose a file contains the single character `*`. Then `IFS=$'\n\b'; for f in $(< file.txt); echo "$f"; done` will not echo a single `*`, but every file in the current directory.

Comment: @chepner Try it this way: `set -f && IFS=$'\n\b' && for a in $(< file.txt); do :; done && set +f`

Comment: Or, I could just use the `while` loop recommended by the link I posted, which doesn't require two calls to `set` and and global change to `IFS`. (Whose previous value you haven't restored.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through your file once and do different things for lines that match or not match:

```
awk '/^#/ {system("echo \"=== "$0"\"")}
    !/^#/ {system("echo \"+++ "$0"\"")}
    ' example.txt
```

Calling system for each line is a lot of overhead, so try to use awk functions.

EDIT:
I do not understand why the file is plit in two streams, the cpp would like to parse a complete file. `echo '#define MACRO "exists"'|cpp -P` is.
Also when you have

```
#ifdef NOTVALID
ignore these lines
#endif
```

I would think the cpp needs to see the second line.
I tried to call

```
awk -v q=\' 'BEGIN {FS=" ";} /^#/ {cmd="echo "q$0q"|cpp -P"; system(cmd)}
        !/^#/ {system("echo \"+++ "$0"\"")}
        ' example.txt
```

But this will be of no use for you.

Perhaps you can exclude the `^#` lines when using other utilities:

```
sed '/^[^#]/ s/e/===replaced the first e in the line by this line===/' example.txt
```

Comment: More overhead than reading and filtering the whole file twice? I need the c preprocessor for one of the streams.

Comment: Why are you using `system` at all? Use the `print` function in `awk`.

Comment: Imy original answer used system showing how you can call a system command like `cpp` for 1 line. However, calling cpp for one line is not useful. When you need to call different utilities on lines without the preprocessor, do it completely inside or completely outside awk end redirect the result through cpp.

Comment: @WalterA I'm abusing the c preprocessor for it's macro substitution, but nothing else. Ended up relocating all of my definitions to the top of the file, which was my original intent behind this question.

Comment: In that case your original approach seems best. You could use awk and write `^#` lines to another stream (stderr?), but you want to append them to the output of the macro stream. How do you know the output stream is finished? Make a guess with `sleep 5` seconds?